# NSTableView as a form - nextKeyView issue (or how to force load all rows)

Tags: macos, swift, nstableview

Perhaps using an NSTableView as a form is a terrible idea, but I've got it working pretty well in every respect except that you can't tab from field to field.

I have a table with a label column and a field column. I also have an array that keeps track of each row in the table with its accompanying NSTextField control. The controls are set in the array as they are loaded during `tableView(tableView: viewForTableColumn: row:)`.

After the tableview is drawn, I run through each control in the array and set its `nextKeyView` to the following control.

This works swell, BUT only for those controls which have been displayed on screen. Because the control isn't added until it's loaded, table rows which are off-screen aren't hooked up.

My current approach (which is awful) is to manually scroll the table several times in order to force everything to load, then set all the nextKeyViews. I haven't got it working very well yet, so I was hoping someone had a better idea. Force-loading all views, if it works, should be an OK solution, but there may be something smarter out there too.

Comment: Intersting. I tried `selectRowIndexes` which selected a row, but does NOT show it. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is

```
table.scrollRowToVisible(<row>)
```

This will show the row you want to see.

Comment: This is a great start, but to clarify let's say I have a table of 20 rows, of which 10 are visible. When someone is editing row 10, I can't set the nextKeyView to row 11 because it doesn't exist yet. Doing this method of force-scrolling to show every row works, but is visible to the user and is ugly. I was hoping for a way that didn't involve actually presenting each field on the screen first.

Comment: You could intercept Tab yourself and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Intercept the Tab, find out which is the next row with an NSTextField, scroll to that row, then set firstResponder? Good thinking. I'll try it out and give you the tick if that works.

Comment: NS(Table)View is a NSResponder and you can implement keyDown to get the tab. I guess it should work. Good hunting :-)